# Data Factory - Multiple sheets into CSV file

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, dataflow

I am attempting to create some derived columns & flatten transformations on multiple excel sheets. My file has about 20 sheets and I need to work on about 15 of them.

This is my current data flow:
[image]

Is there a way to create a loop, so I can select the sheets I want and run them through that data flow, then at the end join them all into one dataset and save them as a CSV file back to Blob Storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Azure Data Factory does not have the capability to know sheet names inside excel during run time.

> Best way is you can save your sheet names in some file or table and
> then use lookup activity to get that sheet names.
>
> Once you get sheet names use `foreach activity` to pass that sheet names
> and loop through each sheet to implement your logic.

**Note:** You should have a data sheet for your excel with parameterized sheet names.

You can have your data flow also parameterized and pass sheet names from the loop into data flow.